# How to add the "Tags" form field type inside the frontend of a custom component

Tags: joomla-3.x, form-fields-types

I would like to add a similar to default articles tag field type:
A dropdown with predefined selects, but someone can add their own values also.

[image: Joomla tags form field type]

What type of field type is this? And how could I add it inside a custom component?

Answer (score 2):

To save me repeating it all here, I'll link to this helpful article that explains it step by step:

http://magazine.joomla.org/issues/issue-apr-2103/item/1225-joomla-tag-field

Comment: Very detailed article, athough it describes the proccess for adding it at backend. Im trying to add it at the frontend.

Comment: The process for adding it in the frontend should be just as simple :)

Comment: Altough i cant find a way to do it :(

Comment: @sin, I can confirm that adding field is not complicated for FE, same as for BE, but you should prepare your custom component to use it. to do this you need to add jtableobservertags and your custom content-type. I can post full explanation if this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **[Tag form field](https://docs.joomla.org/Tag_form_field_type)** type. This field type is available in Joomla 3.1 and newer, and works basically like this:

```
<field name="tags" type="tag" label="JTAG" description="JTAG_DESC" mode="ajax" class="inputbox span12 small" multiple="true" />
```

Note that `mode="ajax"` is required in order to allow on-the-fly tag creation.

More information on using tags in your extension can be found [here](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Using_Tags_in_an_Extension).

Comment: My bad for not mentioning it. I need to add it at frontend not at backend.
At the article you added, there is a way called "Batch Proccessing" but when i add the code it gives me back ONLY the dropdown list .

Answer (score 0):

Use the tag form field type:

```
//Get custom field
$getInput = JFormHelper::loadFieldType('Tag', false);
$taginput = $tags->getInput();
```

https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type#Not_linked_with_a_form